# chat_id = update.message.chat.id | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat'

Tags: python

I've had a Webhook-based serverless Telegram bot running on Google Cloud Functions for over a year with no problems, but this week the following looped error started to occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 99, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 9, in ItapoxBot
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat'
```

Meu codigo em Python 3.8 :

```
# main.py
import telegram
import re

def ItapoxBot(request):
  bot = telegram.Bot(token="9999999999:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
  if request.method == "POST":
    update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id  // <<<=== error

    resposta = criar_resposta(update.message.text)

    # Reply with the same message
    if resposta != None: bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=resposta, parse_mode = 'HTML')
  return "ok"
```

As this error appeared without any change in the code, I imagine that it is caused by an update of the TelegramBot's own library, but I don't know how to get around this error to recover the Bot's functioning that responds to triggers with pre-programmed messages.

Any suggestions to resolve this error?

Comment: Well, `update.message` is `None`.  Why that happen, it's hard to figure out without knowing the library.  The naïve solution would be to add a check for that corner case.

Comment: This problem occurred approximately 60 times an hour and after about 24 hours the problem disappeared and the bot started working again, sending all the messages that were pending in sequence. It must have been a problem with the telegram bot itself.